# How to call a method of a module when site opens in Zend Framework2?

Tags: zend-framework2

I am trying to develop a chat module for Zend Framework. So, whenever website based on zend framework opens, a method in my module will try to connect to the server and then the chatbox will appear. 
My question is how do I call this method. This method lies in my Controller file. Is it possible to call method of a module from another module? Or should I try some other approach?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely achievable. I suggest using events. Here's two posts on Events and the EventManager in Zend Framework 2, which give a good introduction and working examples.

- http://www.masterzendframework.com/tutorial/zend-framework-2-event-manager-a-gentle-introduction
- http://www.michaelgallego.fr/blog/2013/05/12/understanding-the-zend-framework-2-event-manager/